# Transform the Input xml into Output xml using xslt

Tags: xslt

### Input XML structure:

```
<Customer>
   <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>11111</value>
      </item>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>11111</value>
      </item>
   </Order>
    <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>22222</value>
      </item>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>33333</value>
      </item>
   </Order>
</Customer>
```

### Output should be :

```
<Customer>
   <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>11111</value>
      <item>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>11111</value>
      </item>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>22222</value>
      </item>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Order>
      <item>
        <name>ID</name>
        <value>33333</value>
      </item>
   </Order>
</Customer>
```

Here the `/Customer/<Order/item/value` will come dynamically.
Please anyone give a solution for this transformation.

Comment: You do realize that the requested output is invalid XML (you need a single document element)?  Is there an element that is supposed to wrap that content(e.g. `<doc><Customer>...</Customer><Customer>...</Customer></doc>`)?

Comment: @Mads Hansen: About output validation, do note that for `xml` serialization method there are two options, from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method: _"The `xml` output method outputs the result tree as a well-formed XML external general parsed entity. If the root node of the result tree has a single element node child and no text node children, then the entity should also be a well-formed XML document entity."_

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kOrderByValue" match="Order" use="item/value"/>
    <xsl:template match="Customer">
        <xsl:for-each select="Order[count(.|key('kOrderByValue',
                                                item/value
                                            )[1]
                                    ) = 1]">
            <Customer>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kOrderByValue',
                                                 item/value
                                             )"/>
            </Customer>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Customer>
    <Order>
        <item>
            <name>ID</name>
            <value>11111</value>
        </item>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <item>
            <name>ID</name>
            <value>11111</value>
        </item>
    </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Order>
        <item>
            <name>ID</name>
            <value>22222</value>
        </item>
    </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Order>
        <item>
            <name>ID</name>
            <value>33333</value>
        </item>
    </Order>
</Customer>
```

**Note**: grouping `Customer`'s `Order` children by `value`.

Comment: +1 Good solution. I hadn't noticed the grouping of orders when I posted mine. Deleting my answer.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: Thanks. Reposting comment above because I think it has some value.