# XLST transformation from the input xml to output xml

Tags: xslt

### Input xml structure:

```
<Customer>
   <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>11111</value><item>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>11111</value></item>
   </Order>
    <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>22222</value></item>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>33333</value></item>
   </Order>
</Customer>
```

### Output should be :

```
<Customer>
   <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>11111</value><item>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>11111</value> </item>
   </Order>
</Customer>

<Customer>
  <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>22222</value></item>
   </Order>
</Customer>
<Customer>
  <Order>
      <item><name>ID</name><value>33333</value></item>
   </Order>
</Customer>
```

Here the <Customer>.<Order>.<item>.<value> will come dynamically.
Please anyone give a solution for this transformation in xslt based on <Order>.<item>.<value>

Comment: Why you ask duplicate questions? [Transform the Input xml into Output xml using xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309956/transform-the-input-xml-into-output-xml-using-xslt) Remember that you always can update the content or ask for clarification in comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard grouping problem. In XSLT 2.0, use

```
<xsl:template match="Customer">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="Order" group-by="item/value">
  <Customer>
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </Customer>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

If you're stuck on XSLT 1.0, it's a bit more tricky: look up "Muenchian Grouping" (or many replies by Dimitre Novatchev to questions on this forum).